# window.location.hostname without .com or any other prefix

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, window

If the value of `window.location.hostname` gives something like "*example.com*", How can I get just "example" out of the result?

How can I make    `window.location.hostname` return without .com or .org

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hqBKd/4/) is a great fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's a top level domain(and not, mail.somedomain.com), the following code would give you "somedomain" instead of "somedomain.com".

`var basehost = window.location.hostname.split(".")[0];`

Comment: well, +1, But It only works if the user submits `www. + what you need + .rest of url`

Comment: Right.  In that case it'd be index [1] instead of [0]... there is probably a better way to do this.  Mine was very limited in use cases.

Comment: The OP seems to be after the domain name. I don't think there is any regular pattern you can use to determine that, given the variety of possible patterns. The hostname needs to be parsed with some intelligence.

Comment: I tried using window.location.hostname.slice(0, window.location.hostname.indexOf(".com")) but it does not work for localhost.Your solution works for localhost as well! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can't make `window.location.hostname` 'return' anything different as you're using the inbuilt API that your browser provides.

What you can do instead is use some creative use of `String.prototype.split`or a regex to manipulate the string value you get from that property.

Remember to consider cases like `.co.uk` where there is a dot in the middle of the TLD.